# Using EnjoyHint with Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, node-modules, enjoyhint

I have created an angular/ionic app and would like to create some sort of tutorial/walk-through. I looked at quite a few options (including intro.js which was recommended the most) and found EnjoyHint. I really like its style and would like to implement it in my project. However, if I follow the instructions on the [GitHub page](https://github.com/xbsoftware/enjoyhint/) and install EnjoyHint using npm, I get the following error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './jquery.enjoyhint.js' in '\node_modules\xbs-enjoyhint'
```

I played around a bit (I don't remember what I did exactly) and changed the error to:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: global is not defined
```

Has anyone tried using EnjoyHint with Angular? I would also be open to using something else that has a similar style.

I would appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This may help someone save time:**

This is how I used [enjoyhint](https://github.com/xbsoftware/enjoyhint/) in one of my Angular project:

1. npm install xbs-enjoyhint
2. Got same Error:

> global is not defined

1. There are two ways to fix this (at least what I tried :D)

   3.1 Edit [polyfills.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guexn.png)

   3.2 Or [update this in index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27rd4.png) <- (I used this option)

**Note:** Also I imported `"./node_modules/xbs-enjoyhint/enjoyhint.css"` in angular.json

Did:

```
ng serve
```

After this it worked

Answer (score 3):

The npm package has `jquery.enjoyhint.js` in the `src` directory, so I found it worked if I imported `enjoyhint` from the source directory where the relative path could find the necessary files.

```
import EnjoyHint from "xbs-enjoyhint/src/enjoyhint";
```

Comment: If I do this, the font isn't loaded correctly. Do you remember if you did anything else?

Comment: The font needs to be made available.  If you are using webpack, you might use url-loader, I believe.